# How to commit to own PR from other Computer?

Tags: git, github, branch, commit, pull-request

I'm a bit stranded with github:
I forked a repository on github a while ago and made up a new branch on my Notebook. I did some changes and then a pull request. Unfortunately my Notebook got broken and now I want to commit some changes into the PR from a new Computer. How do I get in my old branch, so that I just have to add/commit/push for the same PR from my new Computer?

I tried `git fetch --all`, but my branch isn't there.

\edit:
I just delete the cloned fork and recloned it and then doing the steps written down [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) and it works.

Comment: I think something is missing here.  How did the code base find its way onto your new computer in the first place?

Comment: Ah sorry, i just cloned my forked repo onto my new Computer

Comment: @Droelfeindrittel yes, and I have explained below how to fetch your PR branch into your local cloned repository.

Answer (score 1):

In your new computer, you can [checkout a pull request locally](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally):

```
 git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
 git switch BRANCHNAME
```

The reason a normal fetch has not fetched your PR branch is because of the [default refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec).

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

That would not fetch the `pull/xx` namespace.

Comment: `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` didn't work, it says " can't find remote reference puu/ID/head" but it works when i delete everything and re-clone the forked repo.

Comment: @Droelfeindrittel You did replace "ID" by the actual number of your PR, didn't you?

Comment: @Droelfeindrittel You mentioned puu/ID: was it a typo? It should be pull/ID. https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally does work.